# How can I calculate the uncertainty of two combined uncertainties?

Tags: error-propagation

If uncertainty can be calculated as half the range, and percentage uncertainty is the uncertainty over a mean all multiplied by 100, how can I find what the uncertainty is of A^2 * B^3 when A = 21.3 and the uncertainty of A is +-0.14, and B = 4 and the uncertainty is +-0.01?

Am I right in thinking you just do +-0.14*2 added to +-0.01*3?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*If we assume that $A_\text{min} \leq A \leq A_\text{max}$ and $B_\text{min} \leq B \leq B_\text{max}$, and wish to work out $\min{A^2B^3}$ and $\max{A^2B^3}$, the following is useful. (See [Mark's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1243842/200767) for discussions on probability, spread, independence etc). This is meant more to be a "calculate rough bounds for school physics" level answer.*

The best way to do these questions is to work out the extremes of values and plug them in - though this might not be how you have been taught.

The lowest value is taking: $A = A_\text{min} = 21.3 - 0.14 = 21.16$, $B = B_\text{min} = 4 - 0.01 = 3.99$, thus min answer $ = A^2 B^3 = 28441.33736$

Similarly, $A_\text{max} = 21.3 + 0.14 = 21.44$, $B_\text{max} = 4.01$, max answer $= 29640.3058$.

Actual calculated answer $ = 21.3^2 \ast 4^3 = 29036.16$

So we have:

\begin{align*}
A^2 B^3 = 29036.16 \begin{cases} + & 604.145796 \\ - & 594.82264 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
*(Round as appropriate)*

**Of course...**

You may well have been taught "if you multiply or divide, add the percentage errors". This gives approximately the right answer in most cases, in the above, we get A%Error = 0.6572769953...%, B%Error = 0.25...%, so total percentage error is: $2 \ast 0.6572769953...\% + 3 \ast 0.25\% = 2.064553991...\%$

This gives a rough absolute final error of $\pm 29036.16 * 2.064553991\% = \pm 599.472 \approx \pm 600$.

Note that this is conceptually more confusing, almost more work than our previous working, and we get a less accurate answer. (Here ends my rant about education of calculating errors).

Comment: Many thanks David, in my working I'd had that value but decided against it (I normally don't see an uncertainty that high). It's reassuring to see that is, in fact, the case! You're right on the second point too - I was not aware of the former methodology, so thank you for broadening that out.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Not sure whether to interpret the 0.14 uncertainty on A as 14% uncertainty or 0.14 absolute.  You took it as absolute; I took it (see below answer) as frqactional uncertainty because of the way the problem mentioned percent uncertainty.  At any rate, the "rule" about adding the percentage errors is simply wrong, because the uncertainties add in quadrature if the variates are independent.  And your answer does something which to first order is equivalent to adding the uncertainties, so it is wrong as well.

Comment: the 0.14 was +-0.14 and not 14%. At the A2 level we have been instructed that percentage uncertainties add and that could just be a simplification.

Comment: @MarkFischler Indeed, my argument above works only if $A_\text{min} \leq A \leq A_\text{max}$, and calculates the min and max bounds on $A^3 B^2$. It is however right in that regard.

Having said that, it doesn't account for probability, independence or anything like that. (And, in agreement with you, the OP does say that the uncertainties were taken as half the range).

But, the OP is clearly seeking a lower-level of interpretation, which I am trying to convey in a ready understandable manner.

You are correct; but my answer is not 'wrong' in context.

Answer (score 0):

No, just adding the uncertainties is wrong; and it is certainly wrong to ever square or cube uncertainties and use the results as uncertainties themselves.  You can see the latter by imagining a trivial re-scaling of the variables; quantities like an uncertainty cubed scale improperly.

The way to combine uncertainties depends on certain assumptions about the quantities being combined.  The usual assumptions applicable to your case are:

- A and B are independent of one another.
- The statistical distributions of the measurements for A and B are sufficiently similar to gaussians that you can use the math for combining gaussian random variates.
- The uncertainites themselves are "small", meaning that certain calculations can be done dropping higher order powers of the uncertainties.

In the case of your problem, first we get the uncertainty on $A^2$.  Obviously $A$ and $A$ are not uncorrelated with each other.  The uncertainty with $\sigma_a = 0.14<A>$ is calculated in this dirty but justifiable way:
$$
( <A> \pm 0.14 <A> )( <A> \pm 0.14 <A> ) = <A>^2 \pm 0.28 <A> <A> + O(0.14^2) =\approx
<A>^2 \left( 1 + \pm 0.28 \right)
$$
Similarly, when the fractional error in $B$ is $0.01$,
$$
<B>^3 (1 \pm 0.01)^3 \approx <B>^3 \left( 1 + \pm 0.03 \right)
$$
Then we use the independence of $A$ and $B$ and the Gaussian property of the distributions to add the uncertainties "in quadrature":
$$
<A>^2 \left( 1 + \pm 0.28 \right) <B>^3 \left( 1 + \pm 0.03 \right) \approx
<A>^2 <B>^3 \left( 1 \pm \sqrt{.28^2+.03^2}\right) 
$$
which gives a fractional error on $A^2B^3$ of $0.2816$.